# Mudar valor de variavel js ao clicar em botão e ao clicar novamente retornar ao valor inicial

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho o código js

```
$size = 50;
```

e quero que ao clicar nesse botão

```
<label for="post-1" class="read-more-trigger" onclick="$size = 500"></label>
```

ele altere o valor para 500. Minha unica dificuldade é fazer com que ao clicar novamente no botao o valor volte para o inicial "50".
Creio que seja possivel fazer isso com alguns if's e else's porem sou muito leigo em js e preciso disso.

Comment: Quan é o HTLM de `#post-1`? o elemento tem `value="50"`?

Comment: Não, isso é um botão de ver mais. O que acontecia era que quando abria o conteudo desse botão o scroll suave não ia para o lugar certo já que o tamanho da pagina foi alterado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sinceramente, não vejo muita logica no seu codigo, mas você pode chegar ao seu objetivo usando um operador ternario.

```js
$size = 50;
```

```html
<label for="post-1" class="read-more-trigger" onclick="$size = $size == 50 ? 500 : 50"></label>
```

Comment: Obrigado! funcionou perfeitamente